# Why I can't change the permalink of this page?

Tags: permalinks, pages, wp-admin, admin-menu, options

I have the following problem with a permalink: if I open this page (it is implemented as a static page) on my local website: `localhost/wordpressAsper/archivio` it automatically change it into `http://localhost/wordpressAsper/archivio-2/`

Going into the administration panel ---> pages ---> All pages ---> **Archivio** and editing it I can see that the related permalink is `http://localhost/wordpressAsper/archivio-2/`

So I tried to change it in from **archivio-2** to **archivio** but I can't because when I confirm the change it return to **archivio-2** (but I can change it any other values)

I think that this could depend by an old **Archivio** page (that I have delete) that had **archivio** as permalink. So I think that WP have registered the old permalink of the old page (that not exist yet) or something like this.

How can I fix it and have **archivio** as permalink instead **archivio-2**. Can I reset the old permalinks in some way?

Comment: You may have moved **Archivio** to *Trash* which does not actually delete the page. You may need to go to All Pages -> Trash -> Empty Trash (or delete **Archivio**).

Comment: yes it is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after you delete a page ,on the "all pages" section, on the top, after the "drafts", there is link to trash, go there and delete it permanently, after this you can change the slug name.

Comment: Thank you, Amirmasoud!!! So helpful!

Answer (score 6):

Make sure to check the permalinks of **YOUR IMAGES** also (in "Media"->"Library") as they create a permalink ("post" type) if you upload an image with a filename that is the same as the permalink you are wanting to use for a page.

To Change the Media File URL you need to follow the following steps

1. First, go to the media library, and choose the picture/video/other
   media who’s slug you wish to edit.
2. Next, in order to see and edit the “slug”, who’s display is
   disabled by default, enable the slug edit from screen options on
   the right hand side top corner.
3. Finally, edit the slug to what you wish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Howdy_McGree suggestion. If that does not work, try changing your permalink structure, going to that page, resaving it to what you want, and changing your permalink structure back. Sometimes you kinda have to force WP into a reset.